# Specify non default browser for hyperlinks in MS excel

Tags: excel

I have an excel file which contains hyperlinks. Some of the URLs in these hyperlinks should be opened in specific web browsers like IE.
How can I specify this info in my excel sheet so that when I click on the hyperlink the URL should be opened in correct browser?

Comment: There's no way. I wonder how do you imagine doing that.

Comment: @Taosique Not sure how to do that but I have a real usecase to solve. If it were not inside excel windows shortcut, Chrome's IE tab etc would have been useful. Lets see if someone can suggest something?

Comment: You can open a link in a specific browser using the VBA "shell" statement, but you need to know the full path to the browser's .exe file. How portable and robust does this need to be? Will it just be for yourself, or will it be used on multiple computers with different browser versions installed?

Comment: @TomRobinson Mostly on my computer. So i have the liberty to hardcode the browser version and ins install directory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found one method that works for me using VBA to launch the non-default browser using a URL stored in the cell comment box.

As a bit of background, I also I tried the batch file methods proposed by Eliot Stone and TobyOne in response to [a similar question](https://superuser.com/questions/1220696/execute-shell-commands-from-excel-cell/1220757)  on superuser, but for me each hyperlink batch-file activation required me to confirm in two separate dialog boxes that I wanted to proceed regardless of "risks," which became cumbersome.  The following VBA method does not require any such confirmations.

Here's the VBA code I used:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_FollowHyperlink(ByVal Target As Hyperlink)
    If Left(Target.Range.Comment.Text, 4) = "http" Then
        Call Shell("<PATH_TO_BROWSER_EXE_FILE> " & Target.Range.Comment.Text)
    End If
End Sub
```

In your own code, you'll need to replace `<PATH_TO_BROWSER_EXE_FILE>` with the path and filename for the executable of the non-default browser you wish to use.  Make sure to include a space after the path and before `" & Target.Range.Comment.Text` as in the code above.

To use it, for any cell that is intended to have a hyperlink using a non-default browser, add a hyperlink by right-clicking the cell (Windows) and selecting "hyperlink" or "edit hyperlink" or similar, then under "Link to:", select "Place in This Document", and then under "Type the cell reference:" or similar, enter the Excel address of the cell (self-reference), like "A2" if the hyperlink is in cell "A2."  The purpose of using a self reference is to prevent any other hyperlink action from occurring.

Then, right-click the same cell again and select "Insert Comment" or "Edit Comment" or similar, and then enter the desired URL starting with "http" in the comment.  Be sure to overwrite any auto-filled username so that the only text in the comment is the URL, e.g., `https://www.google.com`.

That's it.  When you click on the hyperlinked cell, the VBA code will activate and open the non-default browser pointing to whatever URL is in the cell's comment box.  One nice feature compared to other solutions that reference the URL placed directly in the cell is that the text in the cell need not be the full (often very long) URL, for instance, simply "Google," and the full URL is hidden in the comment box.